# Submitting inputs without forms with

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I am trying to edit my table rows (img: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViZHb.jpg ) and POST the changed data to my edit.php file. I am trying to do this via jQuery. But when I click save button nothing happens, this is the explained javascript:

```
//Getting all "Edit" buttons in the table (one for each row)
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("clicker");

var savebutton = function(id){
    //Alert the Id of the button to see if the function is being called, and it is.
    alert(id);
    //If I have any $_POST["action"] different from "update" or "edit" I should get redirected to a page apologizing, saying this cant happen. But nothing happens. (not problem with edit.php, because already tried via another way of posting from another page)
    $.post( "edit.php", { action: "test"} );
};

var buttonclicked = function(e){
    if(e.target.textContent == "Edit")
    {         
        //In this function I create a lot of inputs that you see in the picture and cannot be submited one at a time
        e.target.textContent = "Cancel";
        var id = e.target.id;
        var editable_elements = document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable=false]");
        var sub = document.getElementById("sub"+id);  

        var j = document.createElement("input");
        j.setAttribute("type", "text");
        j.setAttribute("name", "subject");
        j.setAttribute("value", sub.textContent);
        j.setAttribute("placeholder", sub.textContent);
        j.setAttribute("style", "width: 150px");
        j.textContent = sub.textContent;
        sub.innerHTML = "";
        sub.appendChild(j);

        for(var k = (id*6); k < (id*6)+6; k++){
            var l = k;
            var index = k -(k*id) + 1;

            l = document.createElement("input");
            l.setAttribute('type',"number");
            l.setAttribute("style", "width: 75px");
            l.setAttribute("step", "0.01");
            if(index <= 4){
                l.setAttribute('name',"g"+index);
                l.setAttribute('placeholder',"G"+index);
                l.setAttribute("value", editable_elements[k].textContent);
            }
            else if(index == 5){
                l.setAttribute('name',"creditos");
                l.setAttribute('placeholder',"credits");
                l.setAttribute("value", editable_elements[k].textContent);
            }
            else if(index == 6){
                l.setAttribute('name',"criteria");
                l.setAttribute('placeholder',"criteria");
                l.setAttribute("value", editable_elements[k].textContent);
            }
            editable_elements[k].innerHTML = "";
            editable_elements[k].appendChild(l);}

        //If any edit button is pressed, create a save button in the same row 
        var s = document.createElement("input");
        s.textContent = "Save";
        s.setAttribute('type',"button");
        s.setAttribute('value',"update");
        s.setAttribute("id", id);
        s.setAttribute("name", "a");

        //Call the function that is supposed to POST all inputs infotmations
        s.setAttribute("onclick", "savebutton(this.id)");
        var clickbutton = document.getElementById("save"+id);
        clickbutton.appendChild(s);

    }
    else //save button has been clicked
    {
        //nothing
    }
};

//If one of those buttons is clicked call the function
for(var j = 0; j < buttons.length; j++)
{
    buttons[j].addEventListener('click', buttonclicked);
}
```

That is my problem...
If you want to see the whole page, its here: http://pastie.org/10578782

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this comment in your code:

> //If I have any $_POST["action"] different from "update" or "edit" I
>   should get redirected to a page apologizing, saying this cant happen.
>   But nothing happens. (not problem with edit.php, because already tried
>   via another way of posting from another page)

```
    $.post( "edit.php", { action: "test"} );
```

When you post via ajax, redirects do not work.  Open the dev tools in your browser and check the network traffic.  I'm pretty sure the edit.php page is being posted to.  You need to use a callback function to check the response of the post action and act accordingly, example:

```
$.post( "edit.php", { action: "test"}, function(data) {
  //data is the response from the edit.php
  alert(data);
});
```

Try this code and see what the alert box says.  If you want to "redirect", you can use `document.location.href = 'whatever.php';` inside the callback in place of the `alert();` statement.

Comment: Ok, the alert data is sending me a bunch of HTML code. And when I use that redirect, it does not redirect me to the apologize page, but to the page I load in edit.php if `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET"`. Also I put a line in edit.php: `var_dump($_POST);` And it shows me the following: `array (size=0)
  empty`
But the network traffic tells me otherwise:
`array (size=1)
  'action' => string 'test' (length=4)
array (size=1)
  'action' => string 'test' (length=4)
C$50 Finance
Sorry!

Invalid action

Back
Copyright © Joao Turolla`

Comment: The HTML I get from alert(data) is the HTML I want to be redirected for right? How do I do that?

Comment: The HTML in the data variable is the response from the edit.php page you are posting to.  If you want to use some of that HTML and display it, then you need to take it, parse it and inject it into the page.  If you want to redirect, just use documen.location.href=''; to send the browser to another url.

Comment: How can I grab that HTML body and display at the top of the page?

Comment: You can use $(data).find('body').html(); to grab just the contents of the body tag, and then you can inject it to the top of the page by doing something like $(body).prepend($(data).find('body').html());

Comment: Glad I could help :-)

Comment: Just an update here, I made a line of code that somehow bugs the jQuery, bunch of erros in console etc, but it does what I want: Redirect me to failure page if posted data doesnt meet the criterias on the URL it has been sent to.
This is the line:
`$('#top').append($("body").html(data));`
Top is the ID I gave to the first element in the HTML containing the cript